# How to store html class content into shell variable

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've been trying to make a script and in this script I would like to update the folder name and a bunch of other things using a variable.

the folder i create is going to be called the latest version release name it has on github.

```
#!/bin/sh
content=$(curl -s -L https://github.com/FAForever/client/releases)
fl=tr '\n' ' ' < $content | grep -E "^<div class=\"release-title\">.*</div>$"
echo $fl



#!/bin/sh
s=$(curl -s https://github.com/FAForever/client/releases | grep "div class='release-title'")
echo "$s"
```

I've looked all over the web for this and noone does this specific setup (source curl/ output shell var)

all have some sort of file input or output or other and I can't make use of their solutions.

what is the correct syntax in shell to grab only one class' content and store it in a shell variable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the github API  https://api.github.com/  returns json which is can be nicely crunched with the command line tool jq

What do you need ? a list of releases ?  ... try this

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/FAForever/client/releases | jq .[].tag_name
```

which gives you output

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  107k  100  107k    0     0   314k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  314k
"0.12.0-pre2"
"0.12.0-pre1"
"0.11.60-p1"
"0.11.61-pre2"
"0.11.61-pre"
"0.11.60"
"0.11.59-pre"
"0.11.58"
"0.11.57"
"0.11.55"
"0.11.54"
"0.11.53"
"0.11.52"
"0.11.51"
"0.11.50"
"0.11.49"
"0.11.47"
"0.11.16+291"
"0.11.14"
"0.11.8+270"
"0.11.7+267"
"0.11.3+247"
"0.11.0"
"0.10.125"
"0.10.124"
"0.10.123"
"0.10.124-pre"
"0.10.123-pre"
"0.11-pre-3"
"0.11-pre-2"
```

if you say "Just show me the latest" then issue

```
sudo apt-get install jq

curl --silent  https://api.github.com/repos/FAForever/client/releases | jq .[].tag_name|sort -n|tail -1
```

with output

```
"0.12.0-pre2"
```

now to bundle into a shell script  vi show_latest.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

latest_release=$(curl --silent  https://api.github.com/repos/FAForever/client/releases | jq .[].tag_name|sort -n|tail -1)

echo latest_release $latest_release
```

which generates output

```
latest_release "0.12.0-pre2"
```

Comment: that's very good although i need it to be something that is preinstalled in ubuntu. right now i get "jq not installed"

Comment: now it shows shell variable populated with answer

Answer (score 1):

Same as Scott's answer but use Python instead.

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/FAForever/client/releases | python -c 'import sys,json; print "\n".join(map(lambda x: x["tag_name"],json.load(sys.stdin)))'
```